# RI-CLPM - Testing whether between and within effects significantly differ

Tags: t-test, random-intercepts

I am currently using a random intercept cross-lagged panel model (RI-CLPM; Hamaker, 2015) to assess between and within effects. For the same variables, we find a negative relation at the between level (correlation between random intercepts), but a positive relation at the within level (deviation at time t as a predictor of the outcome at t+1). I was wondering whether one would be able to conduct a test to assess whether the two effects are indeed different. After some searching, I found that the following formula may be used here, but I am unsure whether that is the case:

[image: Formula]

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Or does anyone know of a paper that attempts to do the same?

Best,
Wout de Vries

Hamaker, E. L., Kuiper, R. M., & Grasman, R. P. P. P. 2015. A critique of the cross-lagged panel model. Psychological Methods, 20(1): 102–116.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this formula would be correct because the coefficients are from the same sample. You would have to take into account the covariance of the coefficients as well. See, for example:

[https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-compare-two-regression-coefficients-in-panel-data-multilinear-regression/#:~:text=The%20t%2Dtest%20is%20a%20statistical%20test%20that%20can%20be,two%20coefficients%20is%20statistically%20significant](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-compare-two-regression-coefficients-in-panel-data-multilinear-regression/#:%7E:text=The%20t%2Dtest%20is%20a%20statistical%20test%20that%20can%20be,two%20coefficients%20is%20statistically%20significant).

https://andrewpwheeler.com/2016/10/19/testing-the-equality-of-two-regression-coefficients/

A simpler way to test this hypothesis may be to constrain the paths to be equal and conduct a nested-model chi-square difference test relative to the model with freely estimated paths. Alternatively, you could conduct a Wald test of parameter constraints in software such as Mplus (using the MODEL CONSTRAINT and MODEL TEST options in Mplus).